# Evitar que letras se corran al imprimir datos en pantalla

Tags: c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, en la imagen dependiendo el primer nombre(Chuck Norris) me corre todo hacia el lado. Busco una forma que independiente del largo del texto las cosas que están a la derecha no se corran.

```
printf("*********************************************************************************\n");
printf("            TABLA DE ESTADISTICAS.      \n  %s:                  %s        Nivel Mapa    POSICION PJ\n",player1.nombre,enemigo1.nombre);
printf("       Vida:%d                Vida:%d           %d           Y: %d   \n       Ataque:%d               Ataque:%d                     X: %d ",player1.vida,enemigo1.vida,player1.nivel_mapa,player1.y,player1.ataque,enemigo1.ataque,player1.x);
printf("                                         \n       Drenar agua: %d         Escape:%c%d  \n ",player1.drenaragua,'%',enemigo1.escape);
printf("********************************************************************************\n");
```

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código de cómo lo estás imprimiendo ahora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tal como lo tienes no sólo el nombre del jugador "correrá" las columnas, también dependiendo de cuántas cifras tenga la vida, ataque, etc. se moverá todo.

Tienes que usar los especificadores de ancho de `printf()`. Por ejemplo, para que la vida siempre se muestre usando dos cifras puedes poner:

```
"Vida:%02d"
```

Así, si vale 8 se mostrará `08`. Si no quieres el cero inicial, puedes poner `%2d`, en cuyo caso en vez de cero usará un espacio. Si quieres que los espacios de relleno en lugar de meterlos delante del número los meta detrás, puedes poner `%-2d`.

Para las cadenas también puedes especificar un ancho mínimo  con `%10s` por ejemplo (10 letras, rellenando con espacios por la izquierda), o con `%-10s` (10 letras rellenando con espacios por la derecha).

<strike>No obstante, no puedes especificar un ancho máximo. Si el nombre mide más de 10 letras, ocupará lo que necesite y por tanto te "empujará" todo. Debes asegurarte por otros medios que el nombre tenga un tamaño máximo y usar ese tamaño en el `%s`.</strike> (falso, ver edición)

#### Ejemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 25;
  int m = 3;
  printf("|%10d|\n", n);
  printf("|%10d|\n", m);
  printf("|%10s|\n", "hola");
  printf("|%-10d|\n", n);
  printf("|%-10d|\n", m);
  printf("|%-10s|\n", "hola");
  printf("|%-10s|\n", "cadena con mas de diez letras");
  return 0;
}
```

Produce:

```
|        25|
|         3|
|      hola|
|25        |
|3         |
|hola      |
|cadena con mas de diez letras|
```

A tí te queda hacer pruebas de tamaño y ajustar la cadena del `printf()`, quitando los espacios que habías insertado manualmente y que deberás reducir para tener en cuenta los que te meterá `printf()` debido a los especificadores de ancho mínimo.

### Edición

Investigando un poco más sobre `printf()` he dado con una opción que no conocía aún, y mira que llevo años usando C. Se puede especificar el tamaño máximo para una cadena con `%.10s` por ejemplo (10 caracteres máximo). Si la cadena es más larga, se trunca. Si es más pequeña no se modifica.

También es válido, y sería lo que te interesa en este caso, una especificación como `%-10.10s` que especifica a la vez un tamaño mínimo y máximo. Si la cadena tiene menos de 10 letras, se rellena con espacios por la derecha hasta que ocupe 10. Si tiene más, se corta al llegar al carácter 10 y el resto no se muestra. Ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("|%-10.10s|\n", "hola");
  printf("|%-10.10s|\n", "cadena con mas de diez letras");
  return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
|hola      |
|cadena con|
```

Comment: si quisieras añadir espacios sin texto por ej. printf("Holaque"); normalmente con espacio dejarías printf("Hola que"); pero no hay una forma de hacer los espacios tipo printf("Hola%4que"); que daría 4 espacios

Comment: @JGUser Lo único que se me ocurre es un "truco sucio", de este estilo: `printf("Hola%4sque", "");`